# Markov chain - how to navigate in transition matrix?

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-probability

> Let $X_0,X_1,...$ be a Markov Chain with transition matrix
>
> $$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ p & 1-p & 0
>  \end{pmatrix} $$ for $0<p<1.$ Let $g$ be a function defined by $$
>  g(x)=\left\{   \begin{array}{rcr}
>     0, &  & \text{if} \ x=&1 \\
>      1, &  & \text{if} \ x=&2,3\\   \end{array} \right. $$
>
> Let $Y_n=g(X_n)$, for $n\geq 0$. Show that $Y_0,Y_1,...$ is *not* a
>   Markov chain.

My attempt:

So I want to show that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y_n=j|Y_0=y_0,...,Y_{n-1}=i)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n=j|Y_{n-1}=i).
\end{align}

does not hold. Substituting in $X_i$ for $Y_i$ i get that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y_n=j|Y_0=y_0,...,Y_{n-1}=i)&=\mathbb{P}(g(X_n)=j|g(X_0)=x_0,...,g(x_{n-1})=i)\\
&=...?
\end{align}

How do I know which states to substitute my $X_i$'s for? I'm pretty sure I should use $P$ to do this but I have no idea how.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your definition of $g(x)$, since both options contain $x=1$..

Comment: Thanks, editing!

Comment: You want to show it is *not* a Markov chain, so you just need to find some $y_0, \ldots, y_{n-2}$ and $i$ and $j$ such that the Markov condition fails to hold.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=j|Y_0=y_0,...,Y_{n-1}=i)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n=j|Y_{n-1}=i)$ is known as the Markov property and is the defining property of Markov chains. So you want to show that this *doesn't* hold. In particular, you'll want to find a counterexample

Comment: @pwerth I forgot to add the text "does not hold" below the Markov property, sorry about that. Oh, so I can simply choose any states that I like such that the proeprty fails to hold?

Comment: Correct. The property will likely hold for certain chains of states but there will be at least one that will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=1|Y_{1}=1,Y_{0}=0)$. Given that $Y_{0}=0$, we must have $X_{0}=1$, from which the only possibility is $X_{1}=2$ and $X_{2}=3$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=1|Y_{1}=1,Y_{0}=0) = 1$.

Now consider $\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=1|Y_{1}=1)$. If $X_{1}=3$, then $Y_{1}=1$ but $\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=1)=p$ and if $X_{2}=1$ then $Y_{2}=0$. Therefore this probability is not $1$ (there is a nonzero probability that $Y_{2}$ will equal $0$).

Since $\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=1|Y_{1}=1,Y_{0}=0)\neq\mathbb{P}(Y_{2}=1|Y_{1}=1)$, the chain is not Markov.

The intuitive reason that $Y_{n}$ is not a Markov chain is because probabilities related to its values depend on knowledge of *multiple* prior states, whereas the Markov property means that probabilities of values of the chain depend only on the previous state.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Thank you! Glad it helped

Comment: May I ask, why did you only go to $Y_2$ and not $Y_{16}$ or so? Did you just use the lowest possible index just for convenience?

Comment: Yes, I simply used the lowest possible index for clarity. But if you found a counterexample going up to $Y_{16}$, that would still be perfectly valid

Comment: One last question, how can we know that the chain starts at $Y_0=0$? You said it's given, but how do I know it's given? Where does it say?

Comment: From your question: "Let $Y_{n} = g(X_{n}), $for $n\geq 0"$